# Directional pad support for Android set top box (not AndroidTV)

Tags: android, react-native

Are there plans for supporting directional pad control in non-AndroidTVs, like a set top box (uiMode = "normal")? I know the directional support for AndroidTV is broken in 0.57.

Comment: How would we know?  Ask the people who write the library (Facebook).  This isn't the place for support requests like this.  Now if you have a question about already developed features of the library and how to use them, that would be on topic.

Comment: I understand your point but the react-native help page suggests asking question here and since the directional pad support is being worked on for androidTv and is broken in the current react version the solution might be more general and apply to my question.

Comment: The react native help page is wrong, this isn't their tech support site. Questions on how to do something in rn would be on topic, but nobody here had any idea on their future plans or roadmap